# how to plot a matlab style graph with opencv in visual studio?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to plot a matlab style line graph using opencv and C++.
and I also found this link https://code.google.com/p/cvplot/ about cvplot.
but still the problem remains because cvplot needs "cv.h" and "highgui.h" to work, and I dont know where to find them.
Does anyone have experience with this cvplot or other ways to plot a graph with opencv and C++?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: cvplot produces very ordinary graphs, imo. Instead I just interface to python and pass commands to  matplotlib via `PyRun_SimpleString(command.c_str())`.

Comment: just be aware, that cvplot is a bit outdated (using opencv's deprecated c-api)

Answer (score 0):

My bad I found where the problem is
I forget to include 
opencv2\opencv.hpp AND 
opencv2/core/core_c.h

Besides, if anyone want to use cvplot in visual studio, better add 
"#define snprintf _sprintf"
or cvplot wont work

Comment: `snprintf` was not part of C89, it was standardized in C99, which is why VS's C compiler doesn't have it. Also, be careful; `_sprintf` does not behave in the same way as `snprintf` (and neither does `_snprintf_s` or `_snprintf`). They don't necessarily add a null terminator, so I hope that doesn't come back to bite you with some weird and hard to debug errors.   `snprintf` *is* however standardized in C++11... but it's not in VS2013.  The 2014 preview has it.